# Configuration Issue: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]

Tags: spring, maven, jboss, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

During JBOSS server startup i get this error,

```
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR] 23813 [main] ERROR org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader - Context initialization failed
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR] org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx]
Offending resource: ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml]
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.FailFastProblemReporter.error(FailFastProblemReporter.java:68)
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:85)
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.ReaderContext.error(ReaderContext.java:80)
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.error(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:281)
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1294)
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.parseCustomElement(BeanDefinitionParserDelegate.java:1287)
19:44:59,307 ERROR [STDERR]     at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.parseBeanDefinitions(DefaultBeanDefinitionDocumentReader.java:135)
```

and this how my application.xml looks like,

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-2.5.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.5.xsd">
```

I am using spring 2.5.6... Any suggestion on the error..

Comment: How are you deploying your webapp to the server?

Comment: Luciano I am coping my .ear file and pasting it to \jboss-5.1.0.GA-jdk6\jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy folder and then starting the maven server from eclipse..

Comment: "and then starting the maven server from eclipse" ? what on earth do you mean with that?

Comment: @Sean i am new to eclipse and maven can let me know what can be done??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This could be because you are missing the `spring-tx*.jar` file in your classpath. Can you verify if this file is in the classpath.

Answer (score 5):

For future references:

If you are using Maven, maybe you forgot the spring-tx dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

Regards